# preg_replace() con multiples coincidencias

Tags: php

Estoy intentando sustituir multiples coincidencias con `preg_replace()` [documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)
pero  sustituye solo una coincidencia.  Me explico

Tengo la plantilla:

```html
Texto completo : 

<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 1
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

    esto no se debería sustituir

<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 2
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

    esto tampoco se debería sustituir

<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 4
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

Fin del contenido.
```

La idea es utilizar el siguiente código para sustituir los comentarios:

```php
$plantilla =  preg_replace("/<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->([\s\S]*)<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->/","",$plantilla);
echo $plantilla;
```

Resultado :

```html
Texto completo : 

Fin del contenido.
```

Resultado esperado :

```html
Texto completo : 


    esto no se debería sustituir



    esto tampoco se debería sustituir



Fin del contenido.
```

Según entiendo lo que hace es sustituir. la primera y la ultima etiqueta. Creo que tengo mal definida la expresión regular.

Comment: en la misma documentacion te dice que preg_replace permite otro parametro mas, que es el limite de sustituciones a realizar. Si lo que quieres es substitutir la primera, puedes añadir ese parametro y jugar con sus valores. Por otra parte, date cuenta que, al ser el mismo tag, el documento esta contenido entre el primer tag y el ultimo tag... (tu expresion regular coincidiria con ese caso tambien)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes usar la versión "no codiciosa" de `*` (Es decir, `*?`) para que coincida con la menor cantidad de texto posible entre las etiquetas de apertura y cierre.

Ejemplo genérico:

```
<?php
$stringPrueba = "Texto completo : 

<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 1
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

    esto no se deberia sustituir

<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 2
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

    esto tampoco se deberia sustituir

<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 4
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

Fin del contenido.";

$stringSustituido = preg_replace("/<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->(.*?)<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->/s", "", $stringPrueba);

echo $stringSustituido;
?>
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Texto completo : 



    esto no se deberia sustituir



    esto tampoco se deberia sustituir



Fin del contenido.
```

Explicación:

1. `<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->` y `<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->` son las etiquetas literales que deseas coincidir.
2. `(.*?)` es un grupo de captura no codiciosa que coincide con cualquier carácter (Incluyendo saltos de línea) entre las etiquetas de apertura y cierre.
3. El modificador `s` al final de la expresión regular permite que el punto (`.`) coincida con caracteres de salto de línea.

Te recomiendo utilizar la página [regex101](https://regex101.com/) donde puedes probar expresiones regulares y a la derecha te explica cada sección de la expresión regular que está siendo probada.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede lograr cambiando el pattern del preg replace de "S" carácter no espacio, por ejemplo a "w" alphanumeric word.
Ver detalles [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$str = "<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 1
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

    esto no se deberia sustituir

<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 2
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

    esto tampoco se deberia sustituir

<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->
    sustituir 4
<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->

Fin del contenido.";
$pattern = "/<!--INICIO_TAG_CAMBIAR-->([\s\w]*)<!--FIN_TAG_CAMBIAR-->/";
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
//Resultado
esto no se deberia sustituir esto tampoco se deberia sustituir Fin del contenido.
```